# AES encryption and decryption source code in C#

Tags: c#, encryption

i'm looking for an AES encryption and decryption source code in C# that get argument like this:

```
byte [] encrypt(byte [], byte [])

byte [] decrypt(byte [], byte [])
```

can anybody help me?

Answer (score 2):

It's built into the .NET Framework as of .NET 3.5.

Use the [System.Security.Cryptography.AesManaged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aesmanaged.aspx) class.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at the AES-related classes in [BouncyCastle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/) (`Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Engines`).